# why does the first code work and the second doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, dom, jsdom

when I put div.main as a separated condition the code doesn't work

```
<div class="user-panel main"> 
    <input type="text" name="login"> 
</div>




 document.querySelector("div.user-panel.main input[name='login']").style.backgroundColor = "red"; // this code works
 document.querySelector("div.user-panel  div.main input[name='login']").style.backgroundColor = "red"; // this code doesn't work
```

Comment: remove the `div.main`. So change your second selector to `document.querySelector("div.user-panel.main input[name='login']")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your selectors are combined with a space - a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) - it's called a descendant selector. So

```
document.querySelector("div.user-panel  div.main input[name='login']")
```

is looking for a `input[name='login']` inside a `div.main` inside a `div.user-panel`.

Since in your html it's just a single div with 2 classes, this selector doesn't find anything.

It would work, however, if your html was looking like this:

```
<div class="user-panel">
    <div class="main">
        <input type="text" name="login"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A space in a query selector denotes one element is inside another. The second line is looking for `input[name='login']` contained in `div.main`, which is contained within another div (`div.user-panel`).